# Position sprite image

Tags: css

I used to have an image that was placed as a background:

```
#myIco{
    background:url(/i/myIco.gif) no-repeat center top;
}
```

So, when I placed that id into a table cell it'll place the icon in the middle of the cell.

I decided to combine all my icons into a single sprites image.

```
.sprites{
    background-image:url(/i/mySprites.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:0;
}
```

The value for the new icon is:

```
#axXh {
    background-position: -33px -83px;
    width: 33px;
    height: 11px;
}
```

But now my icon is no longer in the center of the table cell. How do I fix it?

Comment: Clue: before you were using "no-repeat center top"

Comment: @Diodeus True, but now I have background-position: -33px -83px; where would I add center top?

Comment: I think you'll need to nest a DIV in there and put the BG on the DIV so you can clip the image as well as position it.

Answer (score 0):

That's tricky. You'll have to encapsulate the icon within its own `<span>` or `<div>` and then horizontally position that in the center. I'm a big fan of sprites and stoked that you've decided to use them.

```
<style>
  div { text-align: center; } /* or consider margin: 0 auto; */
  .sprites {
    background-image: url('/i/mySprites.png');
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border:0;
  }
  .icon {
    background-position: -33px -83px;
    width: 33px;
    height: 11px;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <span class="sprites icon"></span>
</div>
```